# Swift - Save asynchronous data

Tags: json, swift, parsing, asynchronous, return

i tried to save data from an API in my app.

But somehow it fails:

```
func getApiData() -> NSArray {

    let ApiManager = RestApiManager(apiUrl:"http://localhost/api/", apiUsername:"user", apiPassword:"password", apiRequestedResource:"resource")

    ApiManager.collectDataFromApi() { responseObject, error in

        return responseObject! // Asynchronous data!! :/

    }

}
```

My manager:

```
func collectDataFromApi(completionHandler: (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    prepareHttpRequest(completionHandler)
}

func prepareHttpRequest(completionHandler: (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(self.apiUrl + self.apiRequestedResource)")
        .authenticate(user: self.apiUsername, password: self.apiPassword)
        .responseJSON { request, response, responseObject, error in

            completionHandler(responseObject: responseObject as? NSDictionary, error: error)

        }

}
```

Retrieving data works great!

When i print "responseObject" instead of returning it, it works.

But how to save it...

Anybody knows how i could save my asyncronous retrieved data, so i can work with it?

Greetings and thanks

Comment: Is there no option for saving asyncronous retrieved data?? ...

Answer (score 1):

Your `getApiData` function cannot return the API data, because when the function returns, the data is not ready yet. This is a concept at the heart of asynchronous programming. Your function starts the network operation and then returns so that program execution can continue while your network operation is working on a different thread.

Instead of returning a value from your `getApiData` function, you could consider passing a completion handler, like the other asynchronous functions in your example are doing. It would look something like this:

```
func getApiData(completion: (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    let ApiManager = RestApiManager(apiUrl:"http://localhost/api/", apiUsername:"user", apiPassword:"password", apiRequestedResource:"resource")
    ApiManager.collectDataFromApi() { responseObject, error in
        completion(responseObject, error)
    }
}
```

Whatever work you want to do to the data when it is ready, that goes in the completion handler. Instead of using it like this (like I think you might be trying to do):

```
let data = getApiData()
processData(data)
updateUserInterfaceWithData(data)
```

you would use it like this:

```
getApiData() { responseObject, error in
    let data = responseObject!
    processData(data)
    updateUserInterfaceWithData(data)
}
```

Of course you would want to check for errors and unwrap the optional data in a safe way, but this is the general structure that you want, I think.